# Python: Problems finding string in website source code

Tags: python

I open a website with urlopen. I then put the website sourcecode into a variable like so

```
source = website.read()
```

When I just print the source it comes out formatted correctly, however when I try to iterate through each line each character is it's own line.

for example

when I just print it looks like this

```
<HTML> title</html>
```

When I do this

```
for line in source:
      print line
```

it looks like this

```
<
H
T
M
L
... etc
```

I need to find a string that starts with "var" and then print that entire line.

Comment: type(source) is <type 'unicode'> or <type 'str'>. Iterating over either of those gives you the individual characters of the string.

Comment: and you really, really, really, don't want to parse HTML with simple string matching, really http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454

Answer (score 5):

Use readlines() instead of [read()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) to get a list of lines.

Comment: Ok I found my data. The problem is the data is the total string is this
var myData = [
["NAME","NUM","CLASS", "ADDY", "ID"],
[...]
];
How can I separate the groups?

Comment: Please edit your question and show an example of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
for line in source.split("\n"):
    ...
```